# Splitting individual element in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0

I am trying to access each element in a `List<string> list` and split each element in the list in my below code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{ 
    string x= list[i].ToString();
    string y= x.Split(':');
}
```

But this is not working, the reason shown is "Cannot implicitly convert string[] to string". How Do i fix this? When i store `list[i]` in a string variable, will it be considered as a string array instead of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `string.Split`, it will return an array of strings which comprise the components of the string which were delimited by `':'`. You need to change `string y= x.Split(':');` to this:

```
string[] y= x.Split(':');
```

See the documentation for the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

this line

```
string y= x.Split(':');
```

returns string[] that is why it occurs

try this

```
 string y= x.Split(':')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Because split returns a array of string. Should be like this:

```
string[] y= x.Split(':');
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the signature of [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)? Its return type is `string[]`, not `string`. Hence you cannot store its return value in a `string` variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{ 
    string x= list[i].ToString();
    foreach(string y in x.Split(':'))
    {
        // do something with y
    }
}
```